# Append string using NSMutableString in loop, with Objective-C

Tags: ios, loops, nsstring, append, nsmutablestring

**Communicator.h**

```
@interface Communicator : NSObject <NSStreamDelegate> {
@public

   NSMutableString *strServerResponse;    
   ...
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableString *strServerResponse;
@end
```

**Communicator.m**

```
@implementation Communicator

@synthesize strServerResponse;

- (void)setup {

   ...
   strServerResponse = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   ...
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)event {
    NSLog(@"Stream triggered.");

    NSMutableString *strSuccess = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    switch(event) {
       ...
      case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
        if (stream == inputStream) {
                NSLog(@"inputStream is ready.");
                uint8_t buffer[1024*6];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:(1024*6)];  //sizeof(buffer)
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            // NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [strSuccess appendString:output];
                            [strServerResponse appendString:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"strServerResponse : %@ ",strServerResponse);
    NSLog(@"strSuccess : %@ ", strSuccess);
}
```

**MainFile.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    communicator = [[Communicator alloc] init];

    communicator->host = @"http://SomeURL";
    communicator->port = 1234;

    [communicator setup];  
}
```

I'm facing an issue in concatenating string. strServerResponse prints empty log where as strSuccess does not appends the last value **since handleEvent delegate is called multiple times.**
Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution after three days of random effort. I changed **NSASCIIStringEncoding** to **NSUTF8StringEncoding** and that worked magic for me! I don't know how changing this can affect the result. Now, I'm getting result from server with last strings being retained in each loop.